# How to store value in an array from text box on button click in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am new to react and trying to understand the useState hook. What I am trying to do is, I have a input type text field and a button. On click of button, I am trying to push the entered value to an array. But currently on doing so, its adding the value to the array but clearing it back and making the array empty. Could any one please tell me why its happening and how to fix it. Below is what I have done.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const HookCounter5 = () => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState({ firstName: "" });
  const handlePushNameToArray = () => {
    setItem(...item, name.firstName);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={name.firstName}
          onChange={(e) => setName({ ...name, firstName: e.target.value })}
        ></input>
        <button onClick={handlePushNameToArray}>Push to array</button>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(item)}</div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HookCounter5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it was getting pushed to to the array except the state was set to its inital value because the whole page refreshed.

- Your button tag is within a form tag. All buttons inside a form tag submits the form, which reloads the page if `e.preventDefault()` is not present.

Solutions (please do **either one only**)

- If you want to keep it inside the form tag, give it a type of button
- Pass `handlePushNameToArray` as an onSubmit on the form tag and remove the onClick callback from the button
- Simply move the button out of the form tag.

Here's the working code

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState({ firstName: "" });
  const handlePushNameToArray = () => {
    setItem((prev) => [...prev, name.firstName]);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={name.firstName}
          onChange={(e) => setName({ ...name, firstName: e.target.value })}
        ></input>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(item)}</div>
      </form>
      <button onClick={handlePushNameToArray}>Push to array</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's how I would do it

1. Use onSubmit to call handlePushNameToArray just by hitting enter
2. Clear input field on submit
3. Show as list

```
export default function App() {
      const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
      const [name, setName] = useState({ firstName: "" });
    
      const handlePushNameToArray = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setItem((prev) => [...prev, name.firstName]);
        setName({ firstName: "" });
      };
    
      return (
        <main>
          <form onSubmit={(e) => handlePushNameToArray(e)}>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={name.firstName}
              onChange={(e) => setName({ ...name, firstName: e.target.value })}
            ></input>
            <button>Push to array</button>
          </form>
          <ul>{item && item.map((name) => <li>{name}</li>)}</ul>
        </main>
      );
```

Comment: Thanks @yubinjodev for the explanation. It helped me to understand what I was doing wring in my code and now its working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the spread operator correctly. While updating state, use array square brackets.

```
setItem([...item, name.firstName]);
```

This method wouldn't work if component is not re rendered after updating name state(this happens because react bathces all the state changes and then updates).
In that case, you can use the other form of useState syntax like below:

```
setItem(prevState => [...prevState, name.firstName]);
```

Use the same for name also.

Comment: Hi Ravi, even after correcting it, my array still getting blank. it just shows the value inside the array and then gets empty.

Comment: No change in the behavior even passing prevState. :(

Comment: Hi @Obraine use it on name also and check.

Comment: Hi @Ravi, no luck even adding prevState on name

Comment: Strange, could you update the code with these changes which are not working.